# Jpa Query Send part of Query as Parameter

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hql

i wan't query like this:

```
@Query(
            nativeQuery = true,
            value = "select vp.id , vp.identity, vp.vehicle_id, dt.i " +
                    "from vehicle_plate vp" +
                    "  inner join (select max(vp2.id) as id, vp2.vehicle_id as vId from vehicle_plate vp2 group by vp2.vehicle_id) as vpg" +
                    "  ON vp.id = vpg.id and vp.vehicle_id = vpg.vId" +
                    "  cross join (values :dates ) dt(i)" +
                    "where vp.vehicle_id in (:vehicleIds)"
    )
    Page<Object[]> findAllJoinByDate(
            @Param("dates") List<java.util.Date> dates,
            @Param("vehicleIds") List<Integer> vehicleIds,
                                 Pageable pageable
   );
```

my problem is the part of query `cross join (values :dates ) dt(i)`  and date parameter unknown by jpa.

should be same as

```
cross join (values ('2019-10-08') , ('2019-09-07') ) dt(i)
```

is there solution for this?

Comment: I have a distinct feeling that you're facing a problem similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55317347/jpql-and-list-of-tuples-as-parameter-for-select-in-statements/55431645#55431645). Can't guarantee the same solution will work for you, though. Also, apart from 'cloning' the rows, does the content of `:dates` influence the result in any way? I can't see anything being filtered using the date list, why do you need it inside the query?