# use jpa nativequery multiple columns in object list array

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa

> Use jpa nativequery multiple columns in object list array

```
List<Object []> queryList = new ArrayList<>();
String[] arr = {"val1", "val2"};
queryList.add(arr);

String sql = SELECT * FROM TABLE A WHERE (A.COL1, A.COL2) IN (:queryList)

Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);

query.setParameter("queryList", queryList);
```

> In postgresql like this

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE A WHERE (A.COL1, A.COL2) IN (('val1', 'val2'), ('val3', 'val4'));
```

> Here is the Exception

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: record = bytea
  建議：No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type
```

**Is this possible?**

Comment: Try to pass List<List> instead of List<Object[]>

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I also think that but don't sure about that.

Comment: I may be wrong, but from my experience Hibernate used to have problems using `List<List>` as query parameters. If that's still the case, you might want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55317347/jpql-and-list-of-tuples-as-parameter-for-select-in-statements/55431645)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to restructure the query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE A
WHERE (A.COL1 = 'val1' and A.COL2 = 'val2')
OR (A.COL1 = 'val3' and A.COL2 = 'val4')
```

This would allow the query to be constructed as follows:

```
List<String[]> queryList = new ArrayList<>();
String[] arr = {"val1", "val2"};
String[] arr = {"val3", "val4"};
queryList.add(arr);

String sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE A "; //dont forget space at end

if (!queryList.isEmpty()){
    sql = sql + "WHERE "; //dont forget space at end


    for (String[] queryParam : queryList ){
        sql = sql + " (A.COL1 = '"+ queryParam[0] + "' and A.COL2 = '" + queryParam[1] + "') OR "; //dont forget space at end and simple colons for param
    }

    //finally remove the last OR.
    Integer indexLastOR = sql.lastIndexOf("OR");
    sql = sql.substring(0, indexLastOR);
}

Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
```

This will also allow the query to be implemented without being native, which is advisable to maintain the JPA philosophy.