# Select from list without duplicates

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a table "Content" like this (other fields omitted)

```
id, name, value
1, test, abc
2, test, xyz
3, test2, abc
4, test2, xyz
```

I'm trying to retrieve the rows from "Content" using an input list like this (list of name_value):

[test_abc, test2_xyz]

I work in Java and I can do some processing on the list before running the query.

Here is what I tried:

First, I split the input list into two lists, first one has all the names and second one has all the values.

Then, I run my query, which looks like this:

```
SELECT c from content c WHERE c.name IN :names AND c.value IN :values
```

I set the parameters to the two lists I created beforehand.

This doesn't work because it will return all the rows and not something unique.

Actual result:

```
(1, test, abc)
(2, test, xyz)
(3, test, abc)
(4, test2, xyz)
```

Expected result is

```
(1, test, abc)
(4, test2, xyz)
```

My query is not good and I'm not sure how I can fix it.

Comment: I don't understand the logic of the query.  Can you explain it?

Comment: You mean something like `WHERE (c.name, v.value) in (:values)` where `values` is a list of name-value tuples?

Comment: Why this results `(1, test, abc)` `(4, test2, xyz)`  and not `(3, test, abc)` `(2, test2, xyz)`. Have you explored the DISTINT operator in SQL? may help you.

Comment: @icrovett I'd assume this is just an example. OP basically seems to want to get specific combinations of name and value instead of all potential matches. Using `name in (x) and value in (y)` doesn't work because this is matching against the cartesian product of x and y while it seems the query should be `(name, value) in ((x1,y1), (x2,y2), ... (xn,yn))`.

Comment: @kranius I haven't used Hibernate in a while and can't test anything atm but could you try to move name and value into an embedded class (e.g. `NameValue nv`) and then try `WHERE c.nv in (:nameValues)` where `nameValues` is a `List<NameValue>`? Alternatively have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55317347/jpql-and-list-of-tuples-as-parameter-for-select-in-statements - finally there would be the "hack" of concatenating name and value and checking for that string, e.g. `WHERE CONCAT(c.name, '_', c.value) in ('test_abc', 'test2_xyz')` but I repeat: that's hacky.

Comment: Criteria queries are also used to dynamically add clauses as required. So for every tuple, you OR in another (c.name =:nameX AND c.value = :valueX) clause to your query.

Comment: @Chris this is what I went with, I chained OR, though I was looking for something more streamlined, maybe I was too hopeful

Comment: Highly inefficient on larger data sets, but you could also keep your input as-is ('test_abc') and run `where name||'_'||value in :list`. To make this more efficient, create an indexed column 'lookup', which is automatically populated by database trigger on insert and edit, so that you can do `where lookup in :values`.